# Devise: rememberable means that last_sign_in_at is not updated by trackable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, warden

I have being using Devise, and relying on last_sign_in_at of the user model to work out if my customers have not returned within X days.  However, I recently discovered that last_sign_in_at is only updated when an actual form log in event occurs, as opposed to when a user is logged in automatically due to the inclusion of rememberable.

If want to ensure that last_sign_in_at is updated each time a user logs in (a new browser session), regardless of whether they used a form to log in or were automatically logged in by the rememberable cookie, how would I go about doing this in a Devise-compatible way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trackable hook is from [Warden's after_set_user](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb) hook -- what you could do to easily remedy this is set a before_filter to call [sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L111).

This could be optimized, but test to see if using

```
before_filter proc{ sign_in(current_user, :force => true) }
```

updates the last_signed_in_at timestamp.

Comment: when does the before_filter get called?  I am hoping not on each request, and only on before authentication for the first time that session?  Also, stupid question, but where do I add before_filter?  I tried adding it to the Devise user model and I got undefined method before_filter.

Comment: That would be run on each request -- it was just a quick/dirty debug step to see if that would solve it before implementing a better solution. You should be able to add it to any controller, ApplicationController if you want it global.

Comment: Hi Rob, this is what I went for in the end which a) checks that a user is logged in before forcing a sign_in, and b) ensures that the sign_in (forced) method is only executed once per session. (excuse the ; instead of line breaks, comments don't allow line breaks) `before_filter proc { if user_signed_in? && session[:logged_signin];         sign_in(current_user, :force => true); session[:logged_signin] = true; end }`

Comment: This is also applicable if you're using the `saml_authenticatable` module, which does not update tracked fields correctly.

Answer (score 15):

Taking Matthew's solution, I think the code should be the following (note the not-operator before the session[:logged_signin]):

```
before_filter :update_last_sign_in_at

protected

def update_last_sign_in_at
  if user_signed_in? && !session[:logged_signin]
    sign_in(current_user, :force => true)
    session[:logged_signin] = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this the best solution yet?

Comment: Got it. You're using a custom cookie parameter to check whether this is a new or existing session. Thanks for the tip, this feels like a much cleaner approach in my case as it means I don't have to dig into Devise's internals.

Answer (score 2):

[Devise: rememberable means that last_sign_in_at is not updated by trackable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788873/devise-rememberable-means-that-last-sign-in-at-is-not-updated-by-trackable)

Expanding on previous solutions, the problem with them would be that if the user signs in normally, they will "sign in twice". Which will set `last_sign_in_at` to the same (or almost the same) value as `current_sign_in_at`.
On my site, I use `last_sign_in_at` to let the user know what has happened since last time they visited the site, and as such I need it to be somewhat accurate. Also, it logs +1 login count.

Also, there are people (like myself) who leave a browser window open for days without closing it (and hence never clearing the session flag). For metric purposes etc, it can be useful if such user behavior sometimes refresh the `current_sign_in_at` time.

The below variants will remedy these things.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :update_sign_in_at_periodically
  UPDATE_LOGIN_PERIOD = 10.hours

  protected

  def update_sign_in_at_periodically
    if !session[:last_login_update_at] or session[:last_login_update_at] < UPDATE_LOGIN_PERIOD.ago
      session[:last_login_update_at] = Time.now
      sign_in(current_user, :force => true) if user_signed_in?
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try the above, using Devise 3.2.4, I do get a new login when it auto-logins by cookie (login-count +1 and `current_sign_in_at` being set). So, I'm left with only the issue of wanting the tracking to periodically update even for users which keep the session open.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :update_sign_in_at_periodically
  UPDATE_LOGIN_PERIOD = 10.hours 

  protected 

  def update_sign_in_at_periodically
    # use session cookie to avoid hammering the database
    if !session[:last_login_update_at] or session[:last_login_update_at] < UPDATE_LOGIN_PERIOD.ago
      session[:last_login_update_at] = Time.now
      if user_signed_in? and current_user.current_sign_in_at < 1.minute.ago # prevents double logins
        sign_in(current_user, :force => true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

On the `application_controller` you can set a `before_action` that checks if the current_sign_in_at of the current user is longer then X ago. If it is, then use `sign_in(current_user, force: true)` that updates the current_sign_in_at.

```
before_action :update_last_sign_in_at

def update_last_sign_in_at
   return unless user_signed_in? && current_user.current_sign_in_at < 12.hours.ago
   sign_in(current_user, force: true)
end
```

I use it so to detect inactive users (not signed in for 6 months) and delete them. #GDPR

Comment: Can you provide some comment or explanation?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can also use `update_tracked_fields!` on that `current_user` model.

Comment: `update_tracked_fields!` takes the request as a parameter. Since devise also tracks IP. Just do this in the controller, `current_user.update_tracked_fields!(request)`.